How expensive is the creation of a ModelContext?
When using modern concurrency in Swift I have noticed that

while ModelContainer is Sendable
ModelContext is not

Which ultimately means that scheduling work in detached Tasks the compiler constantly complains about crossing actor boundaries with non-sendable types if I try to either

create a single context for my actor
simply use the .mainContext available on all ModelContainers

So, what I resorted to is creating a new context whenever needed with a handy extension added to ModelContainer:
extension ModelContainer {
    func makeNewContext() -> ModelContext? {
        return ModelContext(self)
    }
}

Then I just create new contexts whenever crossing actor boundaries:
actor Example {
    private var container: ModelContainer? // initialized from init
    // private lazy var context = container?.makeNewContext() // cannot be used from detached tasks
    [...]

    nonisolated func exampleFunc() async throws {
        Task.detached {
            // cannot use `.mainContext` here because this isn't the main actor

            var context = await self.container?.makeNewContext()
            var items = try context?.fetch(FetchDescriptor<SomeModelClass>())

            [...]
        }

        [...]
    }
}

Is this a good practice? Any other options mentioned are warnings/errors for the compiler. SwiftData seems to discourage reuse of contexts between concurrency domains.

If you want to serialize background work then you would use ModelActor that contains a single context. If you don’t care then you can remove the actor and create a ephemeral context for every Task which I think is fine.
